# Round function in math.h is giving an incorrect output

Tags: c, math.h

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("%f", round((27 + 28 + 28)/3));
}
```

The roundoff is 28 but it is giving an output of 27. Please help

Comment: This is because of **integer division**. `83 / 3` is `27` and passing to `round()` has no effect.

Comment: `round((27 + 28 + 28)/3.0 ) = 28`

Comment: use -->         round((27. + 28. + 28.)/3.));

Comment: I just would like to add that type matters, so keep it in mind while you are doing maths in C or any other programming language. Focus in what kind of data type you want as a result and convert or type any operand to that specific type, which will avoid many issues.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thanks I got it. So if one divides the integer by integer they get the integer value.